# Why does selecting one (or more) tag options in a form created using webform-civicrm add *all* tag options to the user record?

Tags: webform-civicrm, tags

We are on CiviCRM 4.6.19.0 and Drupal 7.50.

I've created a webform using the excellent webform-civicrm. The form is a draft of a data entry/update form for use by staff and volunteers.

I've added tags as a field for contact 2 (the new person whose info is being added, or updated by searching for an Existing Contact) that gets added by contact 1 (the logged-in staff person or volunteer).

I have checkboxes next to each of the 27 tags options, with the multiple selection option checked in settings ("Multiple values will let users select multiple items in this list.").

However, on the webform, when I select the checkbox for any one, or more, of the tags options, and then submit the form, the contact 2 record in CiviCRM shows *all 27* of the tags as having been added to the record.

I added the tag options manually using key-value pairs in the Options settings. In CiviCRM, I removed the parent ID for the issue tags at Administer -> Customize Data and Screens -> Tags (Categories) . Removing the parent ID for the tag did not make a difference.

Any thoughts appreciated. I do *not* want to add 27 separate Tags lines in the webform settings for each of the tags. The multiple values option for the single tags field should do the trick.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm intrigued by your statement 'I added the tag options manually using key-value pairs in the Options settings'.  Can you explain more? Sounds interesting for something I'm working on.

Comment: Andy, see here - https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Webform+CiviCRM+Integration#WebformCiviCRMIntegration-GroupsandTags - especially the section about Option Lists

Comment: Cool, glad to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's my answer, and solution. I started again from scratch. The steps I followed are:

- deleted the Tags and Groups components from the webform
- disabled Tags and Groups in the CiviCRM tab for Contact 2
- re-enabled Tags and Groups in the CiviCRM tab for Contact 2
- added Tags and Groups components back to the webform.

Then, under the Tags component settings in the webform, I selected:

- Static Options (Fully configurable)
- Checked "Multiple (Check this option if the user should be allowed to choose multiple values.)"
- Unchecked Enabled checkbox at top of Options, the default, un-enabling all Tags as options
- Enabled only the handful of Tags I want on the form
- Clicked Save Component at the bottom

I then tested selecting Tags on the form, submitted the form, and only the three tags selected appear in the contact's record.